# Best practices if lambdas are triggered by rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails

I created a controller action like this:

```
def update
  manager.update(
    price_change: -> {
      redirect_to new_painting_order_path(painting)
    },
    price_not_change: -> {
      user_path(current_user)
    }
  )
end
```

It works, but I have a problem in my specs. I want to check if the lambda is correctly called if the price changes or if it does not change. I stubbed the manager object. I can check which params are passed, but I think it's difficult to check lambdas. In addition, I want to check if actions in lambdas are correct.

Are there best practices to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `:price_change` returning?  Could you not write this as an if statement?

```
def update
  if manager.update_attributes(params[:manager])
    if price_change?
      redirect_to new_painting_order_path(painting)
    else
      user_path(current_user)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `manager` is a service object, not a model. I want to have a service object to extract the painting's update process to another object to have a better architecture.

Comment: so you got it working?  check my answer if it helped, but also update your question, i'd like to see how you ended up solving it :)